# Composer-playground command not found?

Tags: installation, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have created whole environment for Hyperledger-fabric but in last while starting web app composer-playground this error occured in terminal for MAC-OS.

fabric-dev-servers prashantgautam$ -g composer-playground
-bash: -g: command not found

Comment: Hyperledger Composer is a deprecated and mostly unmaintained project. IBM's focus has moved to the IBM Blockchain Platform VSCode Extension from Composer

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Composer isn't included with Hyperledger Fabric automatically. Also, Composer's support only reaches to Fabric 1.2 since it is no longer maintained.

If you would still like to install Hyperledger Composer (not recommended) you can follow the tutorial [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html).